# Connect SIM module to a Gumstix?

Tags: gsm, gumstix

Is there a way to connect a SIM module to a Gumstix? I've tried to find commercial solutions (add-on modules) that will do this but have not found any. Surely an addon providing mobile connectivity must exist?

Comment: Just the sim card? Or do you want something that lets you communicate over GSM? Those are two very different requirements.

Comment: SIM module, I want to connect to the internet via GSM.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the gumstix module that you have, if you are using embedded linux with a board that has USB host, then you may be able to use a [USB GSM modem](http://3g-modem.wetpaint.com/page/Huawei+E160+%28E160G,+E160E,+E160X,+K3565%29#fbid=IhB7KWrxtdH) - you stick the SIM card into it and then the module into a USB slot on a gumstix board.  You would have to find drivers or write your own.  A quick search finds that [some people have had success using a particular model due to driver compatibility](http://old.nabble.com/Howto-use-a-HUAWEI-E1752-USB-GSM-modem-td29245533.html).

There are also a number of GSM modules that you can interface with using a UART channel.  They are typically spoken to using an AT command set over a serial port.  If you're willing to explore not having a perfectly clean modular connection (like with the gumstix expansion boards) then there are a lot of options for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a GSM module and SIM card, it would be easy to interface them via a serial port. [This](http://www.gsm-modem.de/gsm-module-modem.html) unit has everything you need on one board. I once designed my own PCB interfacing a Siemens GSM module and SIM card to a PIC controller, it was quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, I'm looking for something that interfaces directly with a Gumstix providing GSM modem capability and keeping the small form factor to boot.

Comment: I don't think that there is such a thing. I might design one, there is probably a market for it.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine that quite a few people would be interested in something like this.

Answer (score -1):

not sure but have a look digi product instead of gumstix.

http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/solutions-on-module/connectcore/connectcore3g

HTH

Comment: That is an independent wireless gateway product using 3G, but OP, imho is looking for a way to connect his gumstix to the net. For generic internet access he could use a regular PC as well.